# How to calculate the Posterior distribution $P(\theta|x,y)$?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian

I'm watching ML course from Stanford on Youtube and on the Bayesian Methods Class, the professor writes the following:

$\theta$ ~ Prior

$y$ ~ $P(y|x,\theta)$

Posterior distribution:

$P(\theta|x,y) = \dfrac{P(y|x,\theta)P(\theta)}{P(y|x)}$

He states $\theta$ and $x$ are independent.

I really don't understand how he made this derivation.

In my calculations, this should be

$P(\theta|x,y) = \dfrac{P(\theta,x|y)}{P(x|y)}$

What am I getting wrong? Are the two derivations the same?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. Just corrected the title.

Comment: The new title remains an issue, I think you should remove the "of"..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the following using Bayes Rule:
$$P(\theta|x,y) = \dfrac{P(y|x,\theta)P(\theta|x)}{P(y|x)}$$

Since $\theta, x$ are independent you can write the second term in the numerator as $P(\theta)$.

Comment: I do understand the term $P(\theta|x) = P(\theta)$ due to independency of $x$ and $\theta$. But the remaining of the derivation is not clear to me.

Comment: If you remove $x$ from the right side of the $|$ sign, you'll see the Bayes Rule. Adding random variables to the right of the given sign for all the terms does not change the formula.

Comment: Ok, now I got the derivation. But I still have a question. Could not P(theta | x,y) also be equal to [P(x | theta,y)P(theta | y)] / P(x|y)?

Comment: That’s also true.